# Cross-compiling using the Android NDK

Tags: android, c, compiler-construction, android-ndk

I would like to use a C library in an app I am working on. Hence, I want to compile it for the different instruction sets of Android devices (arm, armv7, mips etc). It has come to my attention that this is possible using the Android NDK. However, I have not found a clear documentation of how to do this yet. My question is:

*What is the simplest way to compile a C library for a given instruction set (e.g. armv7), using the Android NDK?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this series of youtube tutorials. They are excellent and will show you everything you need to know :

https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1153/introduction_to_ndk

It starts slow but the 03/04/05 episodes are really neat !!

Comment: Extremely useful! Solved my problems!